# Pivotablejs filter function is not calling

Tags: jquery-ui, pivottable.js

I am trying to **hide columns** for the records which are having null or zero values in the **row**, for this I am using filter method achieve. But for some reason filter function is not calling.

Below is the data sample,

```
[
      {
        "cs": 1000,
        "DateTime": "02/06/2015",
        "subject": "lect",
        "math": 1777.655,
        "politics": 0.88
      },
      {
        "cs": null,
        "DateTime": "02/07/2015",
        "subject": "lect",
        "math": 344,
        "politics": 0.99
      },
      {
        "cs": null,
        "DateTime": "02/08/2015",
        "subject": "lect",
        "math": 920.304,
        "politics": 0.777
      },
```

]

Here is the my custom aggregators function and pivotable configuration, where in filter is called.

**pivotUI configuration**

```
               .pivotUI( {
                    rows: ["subject"],
                    cols: ["DateTime"],
                    aggregators: {
                    "math":      successRate,
                    "politics": successRate2,
                    "cs":successRate3
                   },
                   hiddenAttributes: ['Date'],

                 })
```

**Custom aggregator function**

```
      var successRate3 = function() {
          return function() {
            return {
              sumSuccesses: "",
              sumTrials: 0,
              push: function(record) {
                if (!isNaN(parseFloat(record['cs'])) && record['cs'] !== null) {
                  this.sumSuccesses = parseFloat(record['cs']);
                }

              },
              value: function() { return this.sumSuccesses },
              format: function(x) { return x; },
             filter: function(record){ return record["cs"] > 0; },
              rendererName: "TABLE",
              numInputs: 0
            };
          };
        };
```

Comment: Part of the problem is that you're adding a `filter` key to an aggregator, but aggregators accept no such key...

Comment: Thanks! one more Q how can I format cell number?

Comment: https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Localization